# Find if the first visible item in the recycler view is the first item of the list or not

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with 13 data items. I want to find out whether the first item of my list is visible or not?

I am aware about the methods like `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` and `findLastVisibleItemPosition` but they did not tell whether the first visible item is actually the first item of the list or not.

The problem that I am trying to solve is this, I have a view pager as the first item of my recycler view and I want to stop auto scroll when user scrolls down and it becomes completely invisible.

Please help if anyone has any idea about how to do this.

Comment: "if(firstVisibleItemPosition==0)" . I think this is what you need

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by checking if [`findFirstVisibleItemPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition()) is `0` or not, like this :

```
// layoutManager is your recycler view's layout manager
int position = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
if(position != 0){
    stopAutoScroll();
}else{
    startAutoScroll();
}
```

i.e, if `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` returns `0` we should start auto scroll and if it is not `0`, stop swiping.

Comment: Thanks Ashish Ranjan, it worked exactly how I wanted.